# .focus() onblur not working in Mozilla

Tags: javascript, jquery, focus, onblur

I have a textbox where I'm trying to **focus when blur event is triggered** as follows:

```
<input type='text' onblur="$(this).focus()"/>
```

This works perfectly in Chrome and IE, but fails in Mozilla.

How do I solve this?

Here's the **[Problem](http://jsfiddle.net/m2n27399/)**.

Comment: Please don't use `<kbd>` tags to decorate your hyperlinks.

Comment: I'm pretty sure onblur is called when the input still had focus, but is losing focus. The firefox behaviour looks to me like intended behaviour.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Introduce a timer to make sure that your code runs in an event loop separate from the one triggering the "blur" event:

```
document.getElementsByTagName("input")[0].addEventListener("blur", function() {
    var element = this;
    setTimeout(function() {
        element.focus();
    }, 1);
}, true);
```

[Forked fiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/u6wogLca/)

Answer (score 0):

Try to use this.
form,

```
    <form>
        Name: <input type='text' name='name'></input>
    </form>
```

JQuery

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   setupForms();
});

function setupForms(){
    $('input').focus(function(){
        $(this).css('outline-color', '#FF0000');
    });
}
```